# Reverse y axis and bars in MS Chart

Tags: mschart

I am trying to reverse the Y Axis in MSChart

The scale from left to right would be 5 - 1
So if a bar has a value of 2 it will fill from 5 until 2 on the scale with the score to the right of the filled bar.

This link shows exactly what I am trying to achieve

http://www.hfi.com/images/graph.png

Is this possible with MS Chart?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using IsReversed property on the Y axis.